# Laravel API Resource timestamp "Call to a member function format() on null"

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, inertiajs

I'm using Laravel's [API Resource functionality](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-resources) to format my responses nicely for the client, but the trouble I'm having is with the code below;

```php
/**
  * Transform the resource collection into an array.
  *
  * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
  * @return array
  */
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'data' => $this->collection->transform(function ($item)
        {
            return [
                'id' => $item->id,
                'title' => Str::limit($item->title, 32),
                'body' => Str::limit($item->body, 32),
                'created_at' => $item->created_at->format('d M Y, H:i a'),
                'user' => $item->user
            ];
        }),
        'links' => [
            'current_page' => $this->currentPage(),
            'total' => $this->total(),
            'per_page' => $this->perPage(),
        ],

    ];
}
```

When using this code, I get an error; `"Call to a member function format() on null"` on the `created_at` attribute.

But I've already used `dd($this->collection)` to confirm that none of the attributes are in fact `null` and I'm not really sure what could be causing it. My migration contains `$table->timestamps();`, and inside my factory, I'm not overriding the timestamps at all, so I'm not really sure what the issue is.

Here is the test I'm running below to get this error as well;

```php
factory(News::class, 10)->create();

$user = factory(User::class)->create();

$this->actingAs($user)
    ->get('/news')
    ->assertOk()
    ->assertPropCount('news.data', 10)
    ->assertPropValue('news.data', function ($news)
    {
        $this->assertEquals(
            [
                'id', 'title', 'body', 'created_at',
                'user',
            ],
            array_keys($news[0])
        );
    });
```

The extra functions such as `assertPropCount` and `assertPropValue` are sourced from the InertiaJS demo app as I'm using [InertiaJS](https://github.com/inertiajs/pingcrm/blob/master/tests/TestCase.php) in my project.

Hopefully, someone is able to help as I've asked around a few other places and no one seems to know what the reason for this is, and based on my debugging there doesn't really seem to be much of a valid explanation as to WHY `created_at` is null.

As a note, if I turn `$item->user` to `$item->user->toArray()` in the code as well, this then also fails complaining that `user` is null when it isn't. It seems that trying to chain any method onto any attribute causes this null error and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Have you defined **created_at** inside $fillable property of Model?

Comment: @senty On factories it creates them by default. Either way I tried it and didn't change the error.

Comment: @ChiragKhatri Yeah already tried that. Didn't make a difference.

Comment: If you create a dummy User model (without Faker), are the timestamp fields empty?

Comment: @sentry I'm not quite sure what you mean. I'm using `'user_id' => factory(User::class),` to generate my users on the NewsFactory.

Answer (score 2):

First of all keep in mind that the `transform` function you are using alter the original `$this->collection` property, you better use `map` instead that serves the same purpose as transform without altering the original array.
This might be related to your problem because you are modifying the collection you are iterating on, and that can cause issues.

Furthermore, I would suggest you to keep on reading this answer and try out one of the two refactoring alternatives I explained below. That's because I think you are not using API resources correctly and using them properly could actually solve the issue.

**Suggestion about your API resource structure**
The correct way would be to have two separate files: a `News` resource and a `NewsCollection` resource.
This setup allows to define the rendering structure of a *single* News as well as a *collection* of News and reuse the former while rendering the latter.

To implement API resources correctly there are a couple of ways (based on what you are trying to achieve):

**Note**: in both methods, I take for granted that you already have an additional `User` resource that defines the structure to render a `User` model (the `$this->user` property of a `News`).

**1) Create separate classes for single and collection resources**
You have to create two files in your resources folder through these two artisan commands:

```
// Create the single News resource
php artisan make:resource News

// Create the NewsCollection resource
php artisan make:resource NewsCollection
```

Now you can customize the collection logic:

**NewsCollection.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\ResourceCollection;

class NewsCollection extends ResourceCollection
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource collection into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            // Each $this->collection array item will be rendered automatically
            // with the News resource definition, so you can leave data as it is
            // and just customize the links section/add more data as you wish.
            'data' => $this->collection,
            'links' => [
                'current_page' => $this->currentPage(),
                'total' => $this->total(),
                'per_page' => $this->perPage(),
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

as well as the single News resource logic:

**News.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use App\Http\Resources\User as UserResource;
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class News extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'title' => Str::limit($this->title, 32),
            'body' => Str::limit($this->body, 32),
            'created_at' => $this->created_at->format('d M Y, H:i a'),
            'user' => new UserResource($this->user)
        ];
    }
}
```

To render a news collection, you only have to do:

```php
use App\News;
use App\Http\Resources\NewsCollection;

// ...

return new NewsCollection(News::paginate());
```

Laravel will automatically reuse the `News` resource class to render each single element of the `NewsCollection`'s `$this->collection` array when you are converting the NewsCollection instance for response.

**2) Exploit the `::collection` method of the single News resource**
This method is applicable only if you need metadata about paginated responses (it seems that is what you are trying to achieve with your code).

You just need the single News api resource that you can generate with:

```
// Create the single News resource
php artisan make:resource News
```

Then customize the single resource according to your needs:

**News.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use App\Http\Resources\User as UserResource;
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class News extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'title' => Str::limit($this->title, 32),
            'body' => Str::limit($this->body, 32),
            'created_at' => $this->created_at->format('d M Y, H:i a'),
            'user' => new UserResource($this->user)
        ];
    }
}
```

Then to render a paginated collection of news, just do:

```php
use App\News;
use App\Http\Resources\News as NewsResource;

// ...

return NewsResource::collection(News::paginate());
```

---

The first method allow for a better overall control of the resulting output structure, but I would not structure the `$this->collection` inside the collection class.
The responsability to define how each collection element should be structured is of the `News` resource class.

The second method is quicker and works really nice with Laravel pagination allowing you to save quite some time to generate paginated responses with links (that seems what you want to achieve from your code).

Sorry for the long post, if you need further explaination just ask.